# jmeter - how to access dynamic array of variables in scripting?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, web-api-testing, jmeter-5.0

In An API call, we are having an array (the size is dynamic) where I want to validate the the date property of each array element. How can I access these array values dynamically in my script to validate the contents of the fields?

In the debug sampler / view results tree, I can see that for example I have a match NR of 3
and 3 variables.

list_1, list_2, list_3 lyst_matchNR=3

But the size if the list is random, so I can't just hardcode
${list_1} and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of iterating these `list_` variable is using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), just set "Input" and "Output" variables to `list` and it will trigger as many children executions as there are matches of your `list` variables:

[image]

The approach is described in more details for visiting each link found at the webpage in the [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) article

Comment: Thank you very much, I also had a feeling that this might be the resolution.
Just started today, and hard to find a good tutorial, especially that covers everything. (I'm nat that good at digging things up from simply the docs)

Comment: I would have an extra Question here,
If my array would have other properties, eg. ID, createdAt ..etc.

would I also have to create as many ForEach as many property I have in that array? 
Or is there any other / better way?